# HTML Redirect on URL parameter?

Tags: html, url, redirect, parameters, meta

Is it possible to make a single html document have multiple redirects that respond on the parameter of the url?

Like this:

```
URL: "example.com/redirect.html?page1"
-->  <meta content="0; url=somethingelse.com/page1.html" http-equiv=refresh>

URL: "example.com/redirect.html?page2"
-->  <meta content="0; url=somethingelse.com/page2.html" http-equiv=refresh>

URL: "example.com/redirect.html?page3"
-->  <meta content="0; url=somethingelse.com/page3.html" http-equiv=refresh>
```

I hope you know what i mean.

Comment: In 5 years of professional webdesign, I've never seen an approach - and even more important - a reason for doing such a thing. You can do a redirect based on a URL parameter, but for god's sake - why like this? There are many ways, which are more elegant - this solution is bad for SEO and looks like a 90's forum post.

Comment: <meta> only redirect one time, you cant multi it.... If you use JS it possible